# Create an sparse matrix from a list of tuples having the indexes of the column where is a 1

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, one-hot-encoding

**Problem**:

I have a list of tuples, which each tuple represents a column of a 2D-array and each element of the tuple represents the index of that column of the array that is a 1; the other entries that aren't in that tuple, are 0.

I want to create an sparse matrix with this list of tuples in an efficient way (trying to not use for loops).

**Example**:

```
# init values
list_tuples = [
 (0, 2, 4),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 4)
]

n = length(list_tuples) + 1
m = 5 # arbritrary, however n >= max([ei for ei in list_tuples]) + 1

# what I need is a function which accepts this tuples and give the shape of the array
# (at least the row size, because the column size can be infered from the list of tuples)
A = some_function(list_tuples, array_shape = (m, n))
```

Then what I expect to have is an array of the form:

```
[   
 [1, 1, 0]
 [0, 0, 1]  
 [1, 1, 0]
 [0, 1, 1]
 [1, 0, 1]
]
```

Comment: The most efficient way to make a sparse matrix is to create the 3 arrays that the `sparse.coo_matrix` expects - row, col and data.  Read the docs and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values are the `indices` that are required for the [*compressed sparse column* format](https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/csc_matrix.html).  You'll also need the `indptr` array, which for your data is the cumulative sum of the lengths of the tuples (prepended with 0).  The `data` array would be an array of ones with the same length as the sum of the lengths of the tuples, which you can get from the last element of the cumulative sum.  Here's how that looks with your example:

```
In [45]: from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

In [46]: list_tuples = [
    ...:  (0, 2, 4),
    ...:  (0, 2, 3),
    ...:  (1, 3, 4)
    ...: ]

In [47]: indices = sum(list_tuples, ())  # Flatten the tuples into one sequence.

In [48]: indptr = np.cumsum([0] + [len(t) for t in list_tuples])

In [49]: a = csc_matrix((np.ones(indptr[-1], dtype=int), indices, indptr))

In [50]: a
Out[50]: 
<5x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [51]: a.A
Out[51]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

Note that `csc_matrix` inferred the number of rows from the maximum that it found in the indices.  You can use the `shape` parameter to override that, e.g.

```
In [52]: b = csc_matrix((np.ones(indptr[-1], dtype=int), indices, indptr), shape=(7, len(list_tuples)))

In [53]: b
Out[53]: 
<7x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [54]: b.A
Out[54]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

You can also generate a `coo_matrix` pretty easily.  The flattened `list_tuples` gives the row indices, and `np.repeat` can be used to create the column indices:

```
In [63]: from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

In [64]: i = sum(list_tuples, ())  # row indices

In [65]: j = np.repeat(range(len(list_tuples)), [len(t) for t in list_tuples])

In [66]: c = coo_matrix((np.ones(len(i), dtype=int), (i, j)))

In [67]: c
Out[67]: 
<5x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [68]: c.A
Out[68]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```